# Error while running sudo apt-get update from terminal

Tags: package-management, files, cache

I'm unable to perform `apt update` because it throws me following error.

```
Reading package lists... Error!
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-i386_Packages (1)
E: Unable to parse package file /var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_main_binary-amd64_Packages (1)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
E: The package cache file is corrupted
```

Comment: This error occurred while I tried to update through the terminal by using command sudo apt-get update

Comment: What do /etc/apt/sources.list  and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list look like? With all the error messages, a problem in them looks like the culprit